# iphone Json POST request to Django server creates QueryDict within QueryDict

Tags: iphone, objective-c, django, json

I'm creating a JSON POST request from Objective C using the JSON library like so:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request;
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/", host, action]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json-rpc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableDictionary *requestDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[requestDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"12"] forKey:@"foo"];
[requestDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithString@"*"] forKey:@"bar"];

NSString *theBodyString = requestDictionary.JSONRepresentation;
NSData *theBodyData = [theBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
[request setHTTPBody:theBodyData];  
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

When I read this request in my Django view the debugger shows it took the entire JSON string and made it the first key of the POST QueryDict:

```
POST    QueryDict: QueryDict: {u'{"foo":"12","bar":"*"}': [u'']}>   Error   Could not resolve variable
```

I can read the first key and then reparse using JSON as a hack.  But why is the JSON string not getting sent correctly?

Answer (score 3):

This is the way to process a POST request with json data:

```
def view_example(request):
    data=simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data)

    #use the data

    response = HttpResponse("OK")
    response.status_code = 200
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already dealt with this issue. I found a temporary solution as reading the `request.body` dict. I assume you have imported the `json/simplejson` library already.
In my view:

```
post = request.body
post = simplejson.loads(post)
foo = post["foo"]
```

This code block helped me to pass post issue. I think posting `querydict` in `request.POST` has not properly developed on `NSMutableURLRequest` yet.

Answer (score 0):

My cruel hack to work around my problem is:

```
hack_json_value = request.POST.keys()[0]
hack_query_dict = json.loads(hack_json_value)
foo = hack_query_dict['foo']
bar = hack_query_dict['bar']
```

So this will allow me to extract the two JSON values with an extra step on server side.  But it should work with one step.