# Django's Querydict bizarre behavior: bunches POST dictionary into a single key

Tags: python, django, rest, post

I'm experiencing a really bizarre behavior when using the test client in django.

I'm using a `POST` to send data to my django app. I usually do this from an iPhone app and/or a test html form. On the server side, this is how I handle it:

```
def handle_query(request):
   print request
   q = con.QueryLog()
   q.ID = request.POST.get('ID', '')
   q.device = request.POST.get('device-model', '')
   ....
```

That print statement looks like what you would expect, i.e. each parameter in the post request is turned into a key in the dictionary:

POST: QueryDict: {u'app-version': [u'3.0'], u'server-version': [u'v3d0'],

However, I started writing some tests using Django's test client, and no matter what I try, the dictionary of POST parameters I send in the post request get bunched into a single key in the `QueryDict`. Allow me to illustrate with some code:

class SearchTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

```
def test_search(self):
    request = HttpRequest()
    data = '{"amzn_locale": "com"}'
    # request._raw_post_data = data
    resp = self.client.post(
        '/is/', 
        data=data,
        content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        # content_type='application/json',
        )
```

The same print statement on the server side shows the inexplicable grouping of the dictionary into a string:

```
POST: QueryDict: {u'{"amzn_locale":"com"}': [u'']}>,
```

If I set data to an actual dictionary, same thing

```
data = {"amzn_locale": "com"}
```

Setting the request._raw_post_data doesn't change anything. Nor does changing

```
content_type='application/json'
```

Any help would be much appreciated. From this stackoverflow question it seems like I'm not the first one to run into this
[iphone Json POST request to Django server creates QueryDict within QueryDict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579235/iphone-json-post-request-to-django-server-creates-querydict-within-querydict)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're supplying a content_type. Since you did so, the client is expecting a urlencoded string like

```
"username=hi&password=there&this_is_the_login_form=1"
```

instead of a dictionary like

```
{'username': 'hi', 'password': 'there', 'this_is_the_login_form': 1}
```

If you remove the content_type kwarg you'll be fine.

Edit: As it turns out, the test client will look for a url-encoded string if you pass in any content_type other than [MULTIPART_CONTENT](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/test/client.py#L34) - the content_type will only be used to figure out what charset to use to encode that url-encoded string. This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Client.post). The relevant bit reads:

> If you provide content_type (e.g., text/xml for an XML payload), the contents of data will be sent as-is in the POST request, using content_type in the HTTP Content-Type header.
>
> If you don't provide a value for content_type, the values in data will be transmitted with a content type of multipart/form-data. In this case, the key-value pairs in data will be encoded as a multipart message and used to create the POST data payload.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: And of course right on the line above the one I started looking at is the correct answer. post_data is handled differently based on content_type. See the answer below. No need to apply the change below.

So it looks like what's happening is that the data dict you pass in to post is getting immediately flattened by a string encoding function into a string representation of the dict, which the QueryDict later down the line cannot read. I don't know what the intended behavior is, but if you urlencode the post data prior to its getting serialized then it should at least arrive in the required form at the QueryDict. In django/test/client.py we see line 244

```
post_data = smart_str(data, encoding=charset)
```

which just flattens the dict and serializes it. A possible fix would be to apply the same formatting as GET uses prior to serialization, hence

```
post_data = smart_str(urlencode(data, doseq=True), encoding=charset)
```

This seems reasonable to me though I cannot guarantee that it does not have consequences elsewhere. It looks like you could do the above transformation in your code prior to the call to client.post, but I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 0):

But you declared it as a string - you have single quotes around the value for `data`.

Comment: It doesn't matter, look at the second way of submitting data. Even that gets grouped.